# xsd pattern validation issue

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following XSD-type:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="MyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:maxLength value="256" />
      <xs:pattern value="[A-Z^-z-]+" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

in my xml file I have an entry of PECDestinatario which is of the type MyType.
It has the value 'test-value'.
When I use xmllint to validate against the xsd, it fails with the following error:

> element PECDestinatario: Schemas validity error : Element 'PECDestinatario': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'test-value' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z^-z-]+'

If I remove the minus from 'test-value' it validates fine.
It seems that the circumflex is an issue in the pattern - but why (it is not at the beginning of the brackets)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the hyphen in the character range that's likely to be the issue, not the circumflex. The XSD 1.0 rules for hyphens in character ranges are pretty confused and confusing, and they have been interpreted differently by different vendors (Microsoft doesn't even try, they just use the rules from their .NET regex engine).

Try writing this as '`[A-Z^-z\-]+` for better portability.

Comment: Issue remains:

> The value 'test-value' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z^-z\-]+'

Comment: What schema processor are you using?

Comment: xmllint and also the one used in PHP.

Comment: It matches in Saxon, with or without escaping of the final hyphen. I can't help you with other processors. As I mentioned, the rules in XSD 1.0 were very badly written, so it's not surprising that products interpret them differently.